# How to define before tag for only one scenario/feature from more ones

Tags: annotations, puppeteer

I need to run one before tag for specific scenario. How to do that?

So I have one scenario where I need to set up some request like user no.1. I have my one token getting from system based on provided username and password. This is all set up in before tag in hook file - code no.1

Then I need to run another before tag in hook file to get token as user no.2 different user and finish this task. code no.2

I am not able to differentiate it or my system still gets new token like to be always user no.1

code no.1 - it runs each time

```
Before(async () => {
  const page = World.page;
  const token = retrieveToken();
  console.log('Using environment url: ' + EnvironmentVariables.URL);
  await page.goto(EnvironmentVariables.URL + `/?access_token=${token}&expires_in=3600&token_type=bearer`);
  await page.waitForSelector(SelectorUtils.nameSelector(NavigationComponent.searchClientInputName));
  await waitForSpinnerToEnd();
});
```

code no.2 - here I am trying to use annotation with name of scenario but with no effect. I get token but when I look at console I see login details from code no.1

```
Before({tags: '@SubmitSRForReviewFinish'}, async () => {
  const page = World.page;
  const token = retrieveTokenLogin();
  console.log('Using environment url: ' + EnvironmentVariables.URL);
  await page.goto(EnvironmentVariables.URL + `/?access_token=${token}&expires_in=3600&token_type=bearer`);
  await page.waitForSelector(SelectorUtils.nameSelector(NavigationComponent.searchClientInputName));
  await waitForSpinnerToEnd();
});
```

I need to be able to run before tag only for specific scenario. How to do that? How to log with another scenarion as another user?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:by myself

SOLUTION:this solution with annotation works but you need to remember that if you have some beforeAll tag where you set up window and other properties once at the beginning you need to change it to only before tag cause your browser window is still open and no matter what it still gets old values.